# solr facet not returning whole value

Tags: solr

I'm trying to retrieve data from solr using facet

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/prices/select?indent=true&q.op=OR&q=storeCode%3AST01%20AND%20type%3AGWP&facet=on&facet.field=invoice
```

my initial result without facet would look like this

```
PRM://T-A10-1001
PRM://T-A10-1002
PRM://T-A20-1003
PRM://T-A20-1003
```

but with facet it would return something like this

```
"facet_fields":{
  "invoice":[
    "prm",4,
    "t",4,
    "a10",2,
    "a20",2,
    "1001",1,
    "1002",1,
    "1003",2]}
```

what i'm aiming is something like this

```
PRM://T-A10-1001,1
PRM://T-A10-1002,1
PRM://T-A20-1003,2
```

what kind of solution can i use in order to get the result like above, I'm using solr 8.11.1, any help would be appreciated, thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field you're faceting on is analyzed and have an analyzer attached (i.e. it's probably a `text` field or something similar).

Use a pure `string` field for faceting, so that the values aren't being split into separate tokens.

You can change this in your schema, either through the API or by changing the schema file manually. You'll need to clean out the index and then reindex your content to get the proper tokens stored for the field.

Comment: is there any other solution that i can use without changing the schema, because i only get access to read and analyze the data for monitoring purpose